# Select Case not working when cell is formula-driven

Tags: excel, vba

I try to write a code that shows different message box when cell A3 value is different. I find this code works when cell A3 contains text only, but when I try to make cell A3 as a formula-driven cell,this code below does not work. Can anyone help please???

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A3"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Target.Value
        Case Is = "FALSE": MsgBox "This is False!"
        Case Is = "TRUE": MsgBox "This is True!"
    End Select
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: To respond to cell changes due to a formula you need to use the Worksheet_Calculate event.

Comment: I have done this and it works at my side. What is the formula you used in the cell?

Comment: Thank you Tim! This ends up solving my problem! I will post my code in the answer

Answer (score 0):

I guess you dont want to check for the strings True and False but for the boolean values, otherwise it should exactly work like this. May you give us the formula you used in the cell?

If you really have boolean values in the cells you could use:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Range("A3"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value Then
            MsgBox "This is True!"
        Else
            MsgBox "This is False!"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Nirostar - thank you! I think you are getting to the core issue! Yes the value in A3 is essentially linked to a checkbox, if it's checked, A3 shows True, otherwise, it shows False. In this case is this code supposed to work? I also tried to create a formula based on the A3 value (eg. B3= 0 if A3=True, B3 = 1 if A3=False), but it still does not seem to work?

Comment: Then you have a boolean Value in the Range and you can use `If Range("A3") .Value Then Range("B3") = 0`. You don't have to compare it to anything because it is already a True or False.

Comment: Thank you Nirostar! Big help! I was able to finally get it work with this statement as well as changing worksheet_change to worksheet_calculate. I will post my code in the answer area

Answer (score 0):

the code that finally works is as below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
 Application.EnableEvents = False
   MsgBox "False" = Range("A1") = "False"
   MsgBox "True" = Range("A1") = "True"
 Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I find out that i have to make it "calculate" to refresh the sheet, otherwise excel does not recognize the Boolean value change. Also I find that I have to add the "  Application.EnableEvents" code, otherwise, VBA will run into an infinite loop, which does the work, but only stops if you force break and stop the code from running.

Thank you Tim and Nirostar to give the great feedback and inspiration to get it working!